# What is the difference between putting a function in addEventListener vs using function(){ function();} as the second parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Code #1

What is the practical difference between

```
document.getElementById("clearbutton").addEventListener("click", storage.clearStorage);
```

vs.

Code #2

```
document.getElementById("clearbutton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  storage.clearStorage();
});
```

?

I'm practicing JS and HTML and found this weird interaction with addEventListener.
storage is an instance of a class that has a method clearStorage. storage.clearStorage() is suppose to clear the localStorage value of user. When I click on a button with the id "clearbutton", code #1 does not clear localStorage but when I use code #2, it does clear localStorage. That this means to me is that the storage.clearStorage() function is working  properly but maybe something is wrong with addEventListener. Otherwise, I have no idea why code#1 doesn't work as I thought both codes are equivalent. If this is important, this is how I implemented clearStorage().

```
class StorageHandler {
   constructor () {
     this.storage = {"taco": 1}
   }
   clearStorage() {
      console.log("clearStorage runned.")
      this.storage = {}
      console.log(this.storage)
      window.localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify({}));

    }
}
var storage = new StorageHandler;
```

When I run storage.storage in the console of chrome after clicking the clearbutton, using code #1, it shows me {"taco": 1}. But when I use code #2, storage.storage is equal to {}.

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: This is due to scope. For the first example, you need to use `storage.clearStorage.bind(storage)`. Because when the event listener will trigger that handler, `this` won't be `storage` anymore

Comment: @blex: Correct fix, but that's not usually called "scope".

Comment: @Ry- Sorry, would _**context**_ be more appropriate?

Comment: Thanks! Damn that was fast.